# symfony2 saving and retrieving datetime field

Tags: symfony, datetime

I am trying to understand the proper way for saving and retrieving a DateTime field.
When saving the field I have to pass a DateTime object not string like this:

```
//Store a product
public function storeAction(Request $request) {
    $product = new Product();
    $createdAt = $request->request->get('createdAt');
    if (empty($createdAt)) {
        $product->setCreatedAt(null);
    } else {
        $product->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime($createdAt));
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();        
}
```

When retrieving the object the datetime field is returned as a DateTime object but the dataTransformer in the createForm method expects a string..

```
//Show a product   
public function showAction()
{    
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);
    //TransformationFailedException in DateTimeToStringTransformer.php line 138 
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product); 
}
```

The Form builder class

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('createdAt');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\Acme\ProductBundle\Entity\Product',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_productbundle_product';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a type to your field in your form builder :

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('createdAt', 'datetime');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\Acme\ProductBundle\Entity\Product',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_productbundle_product';
    }
}
```